# Add additional headers to Alamofire Session

Tags: ios, swift, http, nsurlsessionconfiguration, alamofire5

Session Configuration:

```
func createAfSession() -> Alamofire.Session {
    let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.af.default
    sessionConfig.headers.add(name: "abc", value: "ABC")
    return Alamofire.Session(configuration: sessionConfig)
}
```

Created Session:

```
var afSession = self.createAfSession()
```

Facing challenge in adding header in created session:

```
afSession.sessionConfiguration.headers.add(name: "prq", value: "PQR") "Not added to headers"
```

I want to add header in session only not in Alamofire's Request.